# BioMart returns one more item

Tags: rna-seq, biomart

I am supplying 30 ensembl ids into BioMart, but somehow it returns 31 result. What is going wrong here?
Here you can see the code:

```
library('biomaRt')
mart <- useDataset("mmusculus_gene_ensembl", useMart("ensembl"))
genes <- rownames(mat)
G_list <- getBM(filters= "ensembl_gene_id", attributes= 
c("ensembl_gene_id","entrezgene", 
"mgi_symbol","description"),values=genes,mart= mart)
```

genes list is the following one:

```
[1] "ENSMUSG00000097971" "ENSMUSG00000097582" "ENSMUSG00000061808" "ENSMUSG00000097206"
[5] "ENSMUSG00000022425" "ENSMUSG00000094708" "ENSMUSG00000095937" "ENSMUSG00000032484"
[9] "ENSMUSG00000060550" "ENSMUSG00000073409" "ENSMUSG00000026822" "ENSMUSG00000056071"
[13] "ENSMUSG00000035299" "ENSMUSG00000045932" "ENSMUSG00000006154" "ENSMUSG00000032496"
[17] "ENSMUSG00000040809" "ENSMUSG00000032690" "ENSMUSG00000055322" "ENSMUSG00000066443"
[21] "ENSMUSG00000005089" "ENSMUSG00000073489" "ENSMUSG00000005800" "ENSMUSG00000034855"
[25] "ENSMUSG00000029417" "ENSMUSG00000029561" "ENSMUSG00000021843" "ENSMUSG00000020108"
[29] "ENSMUSG00000037849" "ENSMUSG00000066861"
```

As you can see I have here 30 genes, but BioMart returns:

```
> G_list$mgi_symbol
[1] "Slc1a2"  "Mmp8"    "Eps8l1"  "Ddit4"   "Ktn1"    "Enpp2"   "Lcn2"    "Cxcl9"  
[9] "Oasl2"   "Ngp"     "Ltf"     "Oas2"    "Cxcl10"  "Mid1"    "Ifi206"  "Chil3"  
[17] "Ifit2"   "Tns1"    "S100a9"  "H2-Q7"   "H2-Q7"   "Ttr"     "Gm10163" "Oas1g"  
[25] "H2-Q6"   "Ifi204"  "Gm10359" "Gm12671" "Gm26699" "Gm26527" "Gm26917"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you print `G_list`, you'll see this half way down:

```
1 ENSMUSG00000060550      15018      H2-Q7      Mus musculus histocompatibility 2, Q region locus 9 (H2-Q9), mRNA. [Source:RefSeq mRNA;Acc:NM_001201460]
2 ENSMUSG00000060550     110558      H2-Q7      Mus musculus histocompatibility 2, Q region locus 9 (H2-Q9), mRNA. [Source:RefSeq mRNA;Acc:NM_001201460]
```

So there are two `entrez` ids that map to the same `Ensembl` id. [One](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=110558) of them maps to an alt locus.

If you exclude `"entrezgene"` from the query, you'll get 30 results.